# Suggest to make tag [c1x] a synonym of [c11] (or merge?), now the Standard is officially released

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

Now that the official C Standard "ISO/IEC 9899:2011" has been released, all questions tagged with [c1x](/questions/tagged/c1x) to indicate the next official C release would refer to this official version. In addition, I found two questions tagged with [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) already, with a rising tendency, I'd assume.

Since I haven't got the required reputation, I'd suggest either a merge or adding a synonym.

I hope this is the way to do it, if not, please enlighten me.

EDIT: I've re-tagged all (11) questions using [c1x](/questions/tagged/c1x) to using [c11](/questions/tagged/c11), see the comments below. But I still think a synonym would be helpful, otherwise we'd have to recheck for [c1x](/questions/tagged/c1x) regularly, and re-tag those manually every time. Can anyone provide a link or some information on what went wrong with [c++1x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1x) vs. [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)? What would we need to avoid?

Comment: There's not a whole lot of them, so manual retagging is entirely feasible. I seem to remember there was some discussion about C++0x/C++11 and the synonym approach didn't work all that well (can't remember why though - something to do with searches?). So just retagging everything with C11 sounds good to me.

Comment: @Mat Sure, but that doesn't link any future questions tagged with c1x to those with c11. And that's what synonyms are for, isn't it?

Comment: Once `c1x` has been removed from existing questions, the tag will get automatically deleted (after 1 day). Given the low number of posts with either tag, C1x is unlikely to get created again. (But yes, synonyms are for that but... what if a new standard gets started, slated for release in 2018?)